# Enqueue script only on child pages of custom post types

Tags: php, posts

I want to enqueue a script on the child pages of two different custom post types. The custom post types are named "Foods" with post id of 10000, and the other is named "Drinks" with a post ID of 20000. The child pages have a slug of `/food/` and `/drink/` while the parents have the slug `/foods/` and `/drinks/`.

The code I have in my `functions.php` file is the following, but it is showing the script on all pages instead of just the child pages of the custom post types. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
function addScript() {
  global $post;

  if ($post->post_parent_in(array('10000','20000'))) {
    wp_enqueue_script('load_script');
  }
}

addScript();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues

The code you shared has some issues: First of all calling a function like this won't work on the bootstrapping process of the WordPress and can't get necessary values where and when necessary, so the conditions might not work as you expected.

**Solution:** Hook the function to an appropriate hook, and [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) is such a hook to work with enqueued scripts.

You used `$post->post_parent_in` out of the context. `post_parent_in` is an attribute of the `WP_Query()` class, that is not available in the global `$post` object.

**Solution:** Instead, you have `post_parent` key with necessary values to compare with.

#### Try out

The following code will [technically] enqueue `myscript` to only on the child pages. The inline comments will guide you for what's the purpose of certain lines. (Not thoroughly tested)

```
/**
 * My Custom Script for Child Pages only.
 */
function wpse357977_custom_script() {
    // If not on the detail page, bail out.
    if(! is_singular()) {
        return;
    }

    global $post;
    // If not on my Custom Post Type, bail out.
    if('mycpt' !== $post->post_type) {
        return;
    }


    // '0 !==' means only on the child pages.
    if( 0 !== $post->post_parent) {
        wp_register_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri() .'/myscript.js', array(), 'wpse357977', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
    }

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse357977_custom_script' );
```